# Pandas sum DataFrame into a larger DataFrame already containing same index with same columns name

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I just want to know if someone have a more elegant solution for the problem below:

I have two Pandas `DataFrame`:

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=list('ABC'))
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[10, 20, 30], [40, 50, 60]], columns=list('ABC'))

    A   B   C
0   1   2   3 
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9


    A   B   C
0   10  20  30
1   40  50  60
```

And I just want to sum the `df2` into the `df1` based on index with the same columns:

```
    A   B   C
0   11  22  33
1   44  55  66
2   7   8   9
```

My solution so far:

```
df_merge = df1.merge(df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True, suffixes=['_l', '_r'])
for elt in list('ABC'):
    df_merge[elt] = df_merge[elt + '_l'] + df_merge[elt + '_r']
    df_merge.drop([elt + '_l', elt + '_r'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df1.update(df_merge)
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`df.add(df2)`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) is equivalent to `df1 + df2`, but allows you to fill in a value where the indices and columns do not align.

```
>>> df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)
    A   B   C
0  11  22  33
1  44  55  66
2   7   8   9
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it will give me a zero line for index 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html) and [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
pd.concat((df1, df2)).groupby(level=0).sum()

    A   B   C
0  11  22  33
1  44  55  66
2   7   8   9
```